# Reachability for Markov process, continuous time

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $X$ be a strong Markov process in the continuous time with a state space $\mathbb R^n$. Consider a reachability problem for this process, i.e.
$$
v(x):=\mathsf P_x(X_t\in A\text{ for some }0\leq t<\infty)
$$
for an poen set $A$. In the discrete time there is an well-known (Bellman) integral equation on $v(x)$. It is necessary condition on $v$, the actual solution is given through the supremum over all solutions of this equation over function bounded with $0$ and $1$.

I am interested if there are similar results in the continuous time. In one paper I've read that if $X$ is a diffusion process then 
$$
\mathcal Av(x) = 0,\text{ for }x\in A^c
$$
and $v(x) = 1$ for $x\in\partial A$. Unfortunately, there were no strict conditions on the process $X$ as well as a strict proof of such a characterization.

I also asked in on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56326/reachability-for-markov-process-continuous-time).

Comment: @Gortaur : Hi I think you might have a look at a paper from Mijatovic and Pistorius "Continuously Monitored Barrier Options under Markov Processes" where if I remember well some results you might be interested in are either proved or referenced. Regards

Comment: Maybe this isn't what you're asking, but it seems to me that for a diffusion the fact that $\mathcal{A}v(x)=0$ doesn't really need a proof

Comment: @ShawnD: well, to claim that something in mathematics doesn't need it proof is rather strong, isn't it? For example, it might happen that $v(x) = 1_{\mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}}(x)$ even for a diffusion.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a consequence of the Kolmogorov backward/forward equations, by noting that the function $v$ does not depend on time. See my answer to your other question for references on Kolmogorov equations https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72426 (I realize this is a bit self-promoting on MO, but I have just seen both questions and they are intimately connected, so I plan to answer both anyway).

But as you said, this is a bit folklore, and I haven't seen a rigorous treatment either - if you have found a source of rigorous proof of this, please also let me know. Intuitive it's quite clear.